# Multiple conditional formatting within one cell ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheet, closedxml

Is there a way to add multiple conditional formatting to one cell?

I'm trying to add more that one conditional format to one cell, but it seems like the last one is overwriting previous one.

```
ws.Cell($"E{ position + 12}").AddConditionalFormat().WhenEquals("SomeString").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.FromHtml("#ff0000"));
ws.Cell($"E{ position + 12}").AddConditionalFormat().WhenEquals("SomeString2").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.FromHtml("#ff0ff0"));
```

According to ClosedXML documentation here [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Conditional-Formatting) I couldn't find anything.
Have someone tried to do this?

Comment: I test your code and it worked for me with no changes.  Both rules were applied to the same cell and functioned as expected when changing the value from `SomeString` to `SomeString2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It seemed that I had ClosedXML in version 0.76 which had bug within **AddConditionalFormat()** method.
Updating ClosedXML to the newest version 0.95.4 fixed the problem.